# Prove that $\lim_{\substack{b\to\infty \\ a\to0+}}\int_a^b\frac{\hat{f}(\xi)}\xi d\xi=-\pi i\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, limits, fourier-analysis

Suppose $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and that $f$ is odd. Prove that
$$\lim_{\substack{b\to\infty \\ a\to0+}}\int_a^b\frac{\hat{f}(\xi)}\xi d\xi=-\pi i\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$$
Here $\hat{f}$ denotes the Fourier transform of $f$.

---

I showed that if $f$ is odd, then $\hat{f}(\xi)=2i\int_0^\infty f(x)\sin(\xi x)dx$. Also, I'm thinking of using this formula:
$$\int \hat{f}(\xi)g(\xi)d\xi=\int f(x)\hat{g}(x)dx$$
for $f,g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$

(Actually I can't use the formula since $\frac{1}{x}$ is not in $L^1$)

Also, this inequality may help:
$$\left|\int_0^b\frac{\sin ax}x dx\right|\le\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin x}xdx$$

Comment: You have a double subscript in both occurrences of the limit which is causing the MathJax code not to be rendered, causing the title and the core of the question to be unreadable to anyone who doesn't know LaTeX. Also, the vertical bars arount the LHS of the last inequality are decidedly too short and should be lengthened via `\left…\right`. I tried to edit the question myself but the edit was apparently rejected. I guess you are asking about a double limit, so could you please add an extra `\lim` before the second subscript so that the expression gets typeset? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

> $$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-ix\xi}}{\xi} d\xi=-\pi i .$$

Comment: Actually I can't use the formula in my original post since $1/x$ is not in $L^1$

Comment: This integral exists in the Cauchy principal value sense.

Comment: Which integral are you referring to?

Comment: But we want to use $\int \hat{f}(\xi)g(\xi)d\xi=\int f(x)\hat{g}(x)dx$ to get the integral in your post. But $1/x$ isn't in $L^1$ so we can't use the aforementioned identity.